# Touch bar auto-complete in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, accessibility

The MacBook Pro’s touch bar offers word level auto-completion in many programs. Is it possible to enable this for Google Chrome or am I stuck with Safari? It is a useful accessibility feature.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it possible to enable this for Google Chrome

Install Google Chrome version 60.

> Version 60 of Google Chrome is rolling out now to macOS with the long awaited Touch Bar support. This release also adds support for a number of developer-focused features, including the Payment Request API and an updated Credential Management API.
>
> After several months of testing in the beta and dev versions, Chrome
>   for Mac is finally rolling out support for the Touch Bar in the stable
>   channel. It’s slightly tweaked with the Omnibox for searching and
>   entering URLs featuring a Google logo, while there is now a bookmark
>   and new tab shortcut.
>
> Users can also change the layout of the Touch Bar by heading to View >
>   Customize Touch Bar in the menu bar. In addition to adding and
>   removing buttons, there is also an option to disable typing
>   suggestions.

Source [Google Chrome for macOS adds Touch Bar support in version 60, rolling out now | 9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2017/07/25/chrome-60-mac-touch-bar-support/)

Comment: I know that Chrome has touch bar support, but I am speifically looking to use auto-completion. I don't know how to enable this, even through View -> Customize Touch Bar. I have Chrome 68.

Comment: @Szabolcs "there is also an option to disable typing suggestions." Auto-completion is not the same as typing suggestions?

Comment: This option is there on all touch bar customization screens in all programs, and I have it enabled. However, in Chrome, I never see the typing suggestions, regardless of whether I'm typing in the address bar or various text boxes.

Answer (score -1):

The chrome implementation of touch bar support only provides static buttons. The auto complete option is a dummy actually.
Read more here - https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/79cboq/in_chrome_my_macbook_touch_bar_not_showing/